Deleting Posts Only from Wordpress Database
I have a WordPress site running locally using Laragon. Before migrating it to my online hosting, I want to delete the posts only from the WordPress database. Not pages, just posts.
How can I go about doing this?
Does anyone know of an online tutorial or WordPress plugin that they can share or step-by-step instructions as I am not familiar with phpMyAdmin.
Ideally I'd like to start with a fresh post count but don't want to lose the pages that I have already created.
If that makes any sense, I'd appreciate the help.
Cleaning up before migrating to online hosting of WordPress website.

Is there a reason you can't use the native WordPress GUI to just delete them? Even if you have a lot, just go into Screen Options, turn on 100 or 999 posts per page, then select all and delete.

Otherwise I would recommend tackling this on the CLI, check out: https://remkusdevries.com/wp-cli/bulk-delete-posts-in-wordpress-with-wp-cli-variants/

Tutorial for the can be found here No extras required, all built in
